Subset table object y using table object x without needing an intermediary step
I want to subset y where values are less than or equal to the corresponding values in x. In the example below, is there a way to skip the intermediary step x1? I couldn't work out how similar questions on SO and elsewhere related to my question. Maybe table objects don't allow subsetting in this way? I am continuing to try, so it would be good to know if this approach is possible.
Here's what I did that worked, but required the extra step:
# Table objects
x <- table(c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4))
y <- table(c(2,3,4,2,3,4))

# Subset x
x1 <- x[names(x) %in% names(y)]

# Result
z  <- y[y <= x1]

z
3 4 
2 2 

I tried:
z <- y[names(y) %in% names(x) & y <= x]

but it returned the error:

Error in y <= x : non-conformable arrays

and I understand why. I also tried:
z <- y[names(y) %in% names(x) & as.numeric(y) <= as.numeric(x)]

z
2    4 <NA> 
2    2 

with the following warning:

Warning messages:
1: In as.numeric(y) <= as.numeric(x) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In names(y) %in% names(x) & as.numeric(y) <= as.numeric(x) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I'm guessing that is just a variation of the "non-comfortable" error.

Does z <- y[y <= x[names(x) %in% names(y)]] solve your problem?

@jared_mamrot - absolutely it does, most appreciated.

Glad you solved your problem @L Tyrone :)
